# Substitution of frequation in Fourier transform of the signal $\hat x(f)$ to $\hat x(\omega)$

Tags: conventions, definition, fourier-transform, signal-processing

In [wikipedia of ESD and PSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density), there is a pair of equations, one is

$$\hat x(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2\pi ift}x(t){\rm d}t$$

We know $\omega= 2\pi f$. How can we obtain then the other

$$\hat x(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\int_0^T e^{-i\omega t}x(t){\rm d}t$$

where does the $\sqrt{T}$ come from?

Comment: It is not really possible to calculate the Fourier transform as it goes from &-\infty& to $\infty$ of the signal. You cannot record such a signal and the calculation will never be done. Hence, in this case, it is limited to a known (measured) interval of the signal $[0, T]$. The $\sqrt{T}$ is a simple normalization so that you will get roughly interval length independent results.

Comment: What does "frequation" mean?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.